# CSS - Unwanted Border-Bottom

Tags: css

Just doing a little touch up before finishing a conversion project and I have an unwanted border-bottom that needs to be removed.

The base code is:

```
a:link, a:visited   { color: #000000; text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #c6132e; }
```

However, I don't want it to show up on all links, particularly the main navigation. When you click on any of the links there it shows up.

On line 56 of the css I placed this code to remove the border-bottom, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
ul#main_nav li a:link,
ul#main_nav li a:visited
ul#main_nav li a:hover,
ul#main_nav li a:active     { border-bottom: none; }
```

Would appreciate a second set of eyes to look this over and help me find the solution.

Thanks!

BTW: here is the link: http://www.rouviere.com/aav/index.html just click on any of the main navigation buttons.

Comment: Is the missing comma after visited a typo in transcription or a typo in the CSS?

Comment: I replaced the comma and still have the problem.

Comment: I don't see any bottom border in the nav menu, both FireFox 3.5 and IE 8 (compatibility mode).

Have you refreshed your stylesheet from cache?

Comment: It's not the bottom border exactly: it's the border around a link shown when you click on it, but not the border-bottom or border CSS property. If you click on the last link (Contact Us) and move the mouse away from the link before unclicking, you'll see the right border too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Timhessel said, it's your focus outline... although this isn't recommended you could add this to get rid of it:

```
ul#main_nav li a { outline-color: transparent; }
```

Comment: Wow - how obscure. I have never seen an outline behave that way, but I am sure glad you figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You missed a comma.  Should be:

```
ul#main_nav li a:link,
ul#main_nav li a:visited,
ul#main_nav li a:hover,
ul#main_nav li a:active     { border-bottom: none; }
```

Your rule is not applying to visited links.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the !important decleration? It may be that your new styles are being overridden somewhere.

```
ul#main_nav li a:link,
ul#main_nav li a:visited,
ul#main_nav li a:hover,
ul#main_nav li a:active     { border-bottom: none !important; }
```

Also, as noted by @iamtooamazing, you missed a comma after the visited decleration.

Comment: !important is not a substitute for proper precedence styling.

Comment: !important would not make any difference in this case as the selectors here are more specific than those in the first bit of CSS.

Comment: You're right, however it's a good way to quickly tell if your styles are being overridden somewhere else. Then you can go back and make the correct changes.

Comment: !important should always be avoided. If you have to use it you either a) do not understand css or b) do not understand css.

Comment: I tried changing it to border-bottom: 0px; and it still shows. Some very powerful code operating there.

Comment: @corymathews: I'm sure that's why the element was included in the CSS spec: to show newbs. No other possible use.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon - unless of course your newest !important is being overridden by another, more specific !important...