# Firefox adding an unwanted border on hover, active and focus states

Tags: css, firefox

**Example of this bug at http://codepen.io/thatgibbyguy/pen/dGYEjE.**

I'm struggling with a bug in firefox on all states but the default state. I've looked at these two links but have not found a solution ([Firefox outline around box-shadow on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571807/firefox-outline-around-box-shadow-on-hover) , [CSS - Unwanted Border-Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915914/css-unwanted-border-bottom)).

What happens is on hover/focus/active, firefox is either drawing a border around the bottom of the button, or it is offsetting the box-shadow by one pixel and creating the appearance of an outline.

**The Code**

```
<a class="lm-button lm-button--primary">Primary Button</a>

.lm-button, .lm-button--primary, .lm-button--secondary {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .7em 1.25em .4em;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 100ms ease-out, transform 75ms ease, background 300ms ease-out;
}
.lm-button:focus, .lm-button--primary:focus, .lm-button--secondary:focus, .lm-button:active, .lm-button--primary:active, .lm-button--secondary:active {
  transform: translateY(0) scale(0.95);
}

.lm-button {
  color: #fff;
  background: #57554f;
  border: 1px solid #57554f;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2em 0 #2f2e2b;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
.lm-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #64625b;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.05em #2f2e2b;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(1.025);
}
.lm-button:focus, .lm-button:active {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #57554f;
  background: #4a4843;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4a4843;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0 #4a4843, 0 0.15em 0.15em #1c1c1a inset;
}
```

I'm stumped by this behavior and looking for solutions.

Comment: Still haven't been able to solve the issue, but a step in the right direction was to remove the box-shadow on the bottom of the button.

Comment: The actual issue is in your `transform` property. It's scale(x, y), you have scale(1.025), Changing it to scaleX(1.025); fixes it. Here's the revised pen.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLNoRr

Comment: Almost! It still leaves little white remnants at the bottom border radius. It's easier to see if you click down on the bottoms.

Comment: That's not your `:hover` declaration then, it's your `:active`. I was answering your inquiry on *What happens is on hover firefox is either drawing a border around the bottom of the button*...

Comment: Weird though, I do see what you're referring to.

Comment: Ah, I'll clean that hover specificity up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not an issue. This might be browser based accessibility.

You can try:

```
selector::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0 !important;
}

selector:focus, selector:hover, selector:active {
   outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't solve the issue. Thanks for the input though!